# Android App and Node.js (express framework) with Mongodb as a back-end

Tags: android, node.js, mongodb

I am new to Node.js and mongoDB.

I want to create an Android Application which has node.js server and DB as Mongo.

Little Background around Android App: I want to develop somewhat like instagram app. My app contains of uploading a image file from android and sends the upload request to node.js server and to store on CDN and mongoDB and fetch that image from DB and display it in android app.

My question is:-

1. How do i acheive this, so do i save first on CDN (How to do that?
   any insights...i googled but i dint didnt find any example in
   node.js) and then save the CDN url in mongoDB.
2. Is this a good approach. Any better alternatives of storing an image
   on cloud and save that image url in mongodb?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This question probably belongs more to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you to use Amazon Cloud Front for your CDN solution. You can use Cloud Front with your private server or Amazon S3, easily. Amazon takes care of all the data caching, distributing process for you. Moreover, sending data from your server to amazon via nodejs is a super easy process. Just use one of the nodejs modules written for AWS [aws-lib](https://github.com/livelycode/aws-lib) or [node-aws](https://github.com/exfm/node-aws). Amazon Cloud Front also handles the security issues for you, just make your content private.